# How to make an app updates a server based on the distance the user has traveled?

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location

I want to get notified whenever a user travel specific distance like 500m or 1km, no matter what the app state is, even if the app is in foreground, background, or suspended. and updated the user coordinates to server by making an api call.

What would be the proper way to implement this?

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html

Comment: and i am pretty sure when apps suspended then it not working

Comment: @NazmulHasan i have tested it today and i can assure you that it works on suspended state as well ... its not accurate though it the updated ranges from 0.6 to 1.4 km range to updated the location with significant location changes.

Comment: Wow that's good news for me , can you share ?how  you done  by answer?

Comment: @NazmulHasan [check this out](https://github.com/voyage11/GettingLocationWhenSuspended)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible if the app is in suspended state, other than that, for foreground/background you can do that.

You can use a timer to check location while your app is in background. please check the following repo, you will get an idea how to do that. https://github.com/voyage11/Location

Comment: [apple location document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html). as mentioned in this link app can be relaunched automatically if app is monitoring significant location changes and region monitoring to deliver location updates from suspended mode.

Answer (score 1):

You only allow to access the location in foreground / background mode. To called location delegate in background mode you need to call `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.

This method will check for 500m changes in location and call location delegate method after 500m changes in between your current location and previous.

Let me know if you have any query on the same.

Thanks.

Comment: but according to apples' documentation the app will automatically relaunched when to notify significant location changes or region monitoring. please read this note from apple :- Note: If your app is terminated either by a user or by the system, the system doesn’t automatically restart your app when new location updates arrive. A user must explicitly relaunch your app before the delivery of location updates resumes. The only way to have your app relaunched automatically is to use region monitoring or the significant-change location service.

Comment: and another issue with significant location changes is that it will not consider distance filter , it will deliver location updates when location changed 500m or more from previous location update.

Comment: That problem will be resoled as per your requirement. If you want to perform action on change distance of 1km. then you can store last updated location and check with new one if you distance between two location more then 1km then save last location and perform your task.